# Can't import socket.io-client in angular project

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, socket.io

Im trying to import socket.io-client into my project but the import line

```
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';
```

is throwing the following error

```
ERROR in C:/Users/USER/Desktop/VSCProjects/CellularAss8/client/node_modules/socket.io-client/build/typed-events.d.ts (30,204): '>' expected.
ERROR in C:/Users/USER/Desktop/VSCProjects/CellularAss8/client/node_modules/socket.io-client/build/typed-events.d.ts (30,239): '(' expected.
ERROR in C:/Users/USER/Desktop/VSCProjects/CellularAss8/client/node_modules/socket.io-client/build/typed-events.d.ts (30,260): ',' expected.
ERROR in C:/Users/USER/Desktop/VSCProjects/CellularAss8/client/node_modules/socket.io-client/build/typed-events.d.ts (30,265): ',' expected.
ERROR in C:/Users/USER/Desktop/VSCProjects/CellularAss8/client/node_modules/socket.io-client/build/typed-events.d.ts (30,296): '(' expected.
ERROR in C:/Users/USER/Desktop/VSCProjects/CellularAss8/client/node_modules/socket.io-client/build/typed-events.d.ts (30,313): ',' expected.
ERROR in C:/Users/USER/Desktop/VSCProjects/CellularAss8/client/node_modules/socket.io-client/build/typed-events.d.ts (30,321): Expression expected.
ERROR in C:/Users/USER/Desktop/VSCProjects/CellularAss8/client/node_modules/socket.io-client/build/typed-events.d.ts (37,49): ';' expected.
ERROR in C:/Users/USER/Desktop/VSCProjects/CellularAss8/client/node_modules/socket.io-client/build/typed-events.d.ts (37,92): Expression expected.
ERROR in C:/Users/USER/Desktop/VSCProjects/CellularAss8/client/node_modules/socket.io-client/build/typed-events.d.ts (21,86): Cannot find name 'Parameters'.
ERROR in C:/Users/USER/Desktop/VSCProjects/CellularAss8/client/node_modules/socket.io-client/build/typed-events.d.ts (30,212): 'EventNames' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
ERROR in C:/Users/USER/Desktop/VSCProjects/CellularAss8/client/node_modules/socket.io-client/build/typed-events.d.ts (30,241): Cannot find name 'ReservedEvents'.
ERROR in C:/Users/USER/Desktop/VSCProjects/CellularAss8/client/node_modules/socket.io-client/build/typed-events.d.ts (30,256): Cannot find name 'Ev'.
ERROR in C:/Users/USER/Desktop/VSCProjects/CellularAss8/client/node_modules/socket.io-client/build/typed-events.d.ts (30,262): Cannot find name 'Ev'.
ERROR in C:/Users/USER/Desktop/VSCProjects/CellularAss8/client/node_modules/socket.io-client/build/typed-events.d.ts (30,273): 'EventNames' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
ERROR in C:/Users/USER/Desktop/VSCProjects/CellularAss8/client/node_modules/socket.io-client/build/typed-events.d.ts (30,298): Cannot find name 'UserEvents'.
ERROR in C:/Users/USER/Desktop/VSCProjects/CellularAss8/client/node_modules/socket.io-client/build/typed-events.d.ts (30,309): Cannot find name 'Ev'.
ERROR in C:/Users/USER/Desktop/VSCProjects/CellularAss8/client/node_modules/socket.io-client/build/typed-events.d.ts (30,315): Cannot find name 'never'.
ERROR in C:/Users/USER/Desktop/VSCProjects/CellularAss8/client/node_modules/socket.io-client/build/typed-events.d.ts (37,58): Cannot find name 'never'.
ERROR in C:/Users/USER/Desktop/VSCProjects/CellularAss8/client/node_modules/socket.io-client/build/typed-events.d.ts (37,94): Cannot find name 'T'.
ERROR in C:/Users/USER/Desktop/VSCProjects/CellularAss8/client/node_modules/socket.io-client/build/typed-events.d.ts (51,31): Class 'StrictEventEmitter<ListenEvents, EmitEvents, ReservedEvents>' incorrectly extends base class 'Emitter<string>'.
  Types of property 'on' are incompatible.
    Type '<Ev extends ReservedOrUserEventNames<ReservedEvents, ListenEvents>>(ev: Ev, listener: [Ev]) => this' is not assignable to type '(event: string, listener: Function) => Emitter<string>'.
      Types of parameters 'listener' and 'listener' are incompatible.
        Type 'Function' is not assignable to type '[any]'.
          Property '0' is missing in type 'Function'.
ERROR in C:/Users/USER/Desktop/VSCProjects/CellularAss8/client/node_modules/socket.io-client/build/typed-events.d.ts (72,53): A rest parameter must be of an array type.
ERROR in C:/Users/USER/Desktop/VSCProjects/CellularAss8/client/node_modules/socket.io-client/build/typed-events.d.ts (82,75): A rest parameter must be of an array type.
ERROR in C:/Users/USER/Desktop/VSCProjects/CellularAss8/client/node_modules/socket.io-client/build/socket.d.ts (48,9): An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
ERROR in C:/Users/USER/Desktop/VSCProjects/CellularAss8/client/node_modules/socket.io-client/build/socket.d.ts (73,53): A rest parameter must be of an array type.
ERROR in C:/Users/USER/Desktop/VSCProjects/CellularAss8/client/node_modules/socket.io-client/build/socket.d.ts (184,9): An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
```

After digging around for a bit I found that while being in angular debug mode, if I comment the import line out, save, uncomment and save the code run perfectly in debug mode.

Is there anyway to fix it so the import will work without the steps i mention above?

Angular version is 4.4.6
and socket.io-client version is 1.7.3

and here is the tsconfig.json file

```json
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "lib": ["es2017", "dom"]
  },
  "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
}
```

Comment: You need to provide more information about your project, because the import statement on its own is perfectly valid.

Comment: I added the packages versions, and the tsconfig.json file

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your issue. Can you provide reproduction repo?

Comment: sure, https://github.com/DanielBotnik/ButtonsGame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using socket.io-client in version 1.7.3 but rather version `^4.1.3`.  That one defacto creates dependency on typescript 4 thanks to its packed type definition files but your project compiles with typescript `~2.3.3`. Hence the error you are getting.

Make sure to install the correct version with `npm i -S socket.io-client@1.7.3`. It doesn't pack its own type definitions though (so it creates no dependency on typescript), so you will also need to install `@types/socket.io-client@1` to get the types.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the issue you mention but I might be able to provide a workaround.

You can try using this package instead https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-socket-io while working with Angular and Socket.io. I've used it in the past and it works well, it might solve your problem.

Simply install it and then configure it. Something like:

```
import { SocketIoModule, SocketIoConfig } from 'ngx-socket-io';

const config: SocketIoConfig = { url: 'http://localhost:8988', options: {} };

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, SocketIoModule.forRoot(config)],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```